# How to load base url axios from env in nuxt js

Tags: vue.js, axios, environment-variables, nuxt.js

So first of all, I have 2 env file,

`env.dev`

```
BASE_URL=xxxx
```

`.env`

```
BASE_URL=xxxx
```

I tried to load `BASE_URL` from my env file, so I use [nuxt/dotenv](https://github.com/nuxt-community/dotenv-module) to load env file on `nuxt.config.js`, like this,

```js
buildModules: [
  '@nuxtjs/eslint-module',
  ['@nuxtjs/dotenv', { filename: '.env' + process.env.ENV }]
],
modules: [
  '@nuxtjs/axios',
  '@nuxtjs/auth',
  '@nuxtjs/dotenv'
],
axios: {
  baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL,
  redirectError: {
    401: '/login',
    403: '/login',
    404: '/notfound'
  }
}
```

But when I try to hit API login, it's always pointing to `BASE_URL` on `.env`.
What am I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Here I wrote a quick answer on how to user env variables: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67705541/8816585

Here is an answer on how to use a specific `.env.dev` file: https://github.com/nuxt-community/dotenv-module/issues/59#issuecomment-660646526

```
yarn add -D @nuxtjs/dotenv
```

In `nuxt.config.js`

```js
modules: ['@nuxtjs/dotenv'],
...
buildModules: [
  ['@nuxtjs/dotenv', 
    { filename: '.env.' + process.env.ENV }
  ]
],
```

In `package.json` (your probably missed this one)

```json
"scripts": { "dev": "ENV=dev nuxt" }
```

And finally, do not forget to add them all to your `.gitignore` file.

Meanwhile, this way of working is not the recommended way as stated in the official `dotenv` project: https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#should-i-have-multiple-env-files