# How to set axios as a default prototype for Nuxt.js and append token to the default axios authorization header?

Tags: axios, local-storage, nuxt.js, nuxt-auth

In Vue.js simply we can include axios as our deafault prototype for Vue.js and append local storage token to a default axios authorization header in the Vue main.js file .

As follows:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import axios from 'axios'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.prototype.$http = axios;
const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
if(token){
  Vue.prototype.$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token;
}

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

My question is how to set axios as a default prototype for Nuxt.js and append local storage token to a default axios authorization header inside the `Nuxt.config.js` File

Answer (score 3):

Not sure that the prototype is the way to go usually.

I do recommend this one for Nuxt
Install [`nuxt/axios`](https://axios.nuxtjs.org/setup) with
`yarn add @nuxtjs/axios`

Then, go to your Nuxt configuration
`nuxt.config.js`

```js
plugins: ['@/plugins/nuxt-axios.js'],
modules: ['@nuxtjs/axios'],
```

And set the configuration to your axios as you wish
`/plugins/nuxt-axios.js`

```js
export default ({ $axios }, $config: { authorizationToken }) => {
  $axios.defaults.headers.Authorization = authorizationToken
}
```

Or directly in the configuration file
`nuxt.config.js`

```js
axios: {
  headers: {
    Authorization: process.env.TOKEN,
  },
},
```

---

If you wish more info with the env variables, you can check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67705541/8816585