# I want to use this. $ axios with Vuex constants

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, vuex

## What I want to come true

I use `this.$axios` many times, so I tried to put it in a constant, but it doesn't work.
I read the official docs but didn't understand.
Is it because `this` isn't available in the Nuxt.js lifecycle?

## Code

**url.js**

```js
export const AXIOS_POST = this.$axios.$post

export const POST_API = '/api/v1/'

export const POST_ITEMS_API = '/api/v1/post_items/'
```

**Vuex**

```js
import * as api from './constants/url.js'  // url.js in this.

export const state = () => ({
  list: [],
  hidden: false
})

export const mutations = {
  
  add (state, response) {
    state.list.push({
      content: response.content,
      status: response.status
    })
  },


  remove (state, todo) {
    state.list.splice(state.list.indexOf(todo), 1)
  },


  edit (state, { todo, text }) {
    state.list.splice(state.list.indexOf(todo), 1, { text })
  },


  toggle (state, todo) {
    todo.status = !todo.status
  },

  cancel (state, todo) {
    todo.status = false
  },

  // アクション登録パネルフラグ
  switching (state) {
    state.hidden = !state.hidden
  }
}

export const actions = {

  post ({ commit }, text) {

//I want to use it here

    this.$axios.$post(api.POST_ITEMS_API + 'posts', {
      post_items: {
        content: text,
        status: false
      }
    })
      .then((response) => {
        commit('add', response)
      })
  }
}
```

## Error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$axios' of undefined

Comment: in utitlty, import vue and use vue.$axios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your file is located into a `constants` directory, you should probably use some `.env` file.
Here is a guide on how to achieve this in Nuxt: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67705541/8816585

---

If you really want to have access to it into a non `.vue` file, you can import it as usual with something like this

`/constants/url.js`

```js
import store from '~/store/index'

export const test = () => {
  // the line below depends of your store of course
  return store.modules['@me'].state.email
}
```

PS: `getters`, `dispatch` and everything alike is available here.

Then call it in a page or `.vue` component like this

```js
<script>
import { test } from '~/constants/url'

export default {
  mounted() {
    console.log('call the store here', test())
  },
}
</script>
```

---

As for the lifecyle question, since the `url.js` file is not in a `.vue` file but a regular JS one, it has no idea about any **Vue/Nuxt** lifecycles.

Comment: Sorry for late reply and thank you for your comment.
I understand I have to use axios from env.Access axios from the argument of export defaulet.