# How to use .env value in nuxt.config.js with runtime config

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm searching how to use a .env value in nuxt.config.js with runtime config.

Declare it, to use it in "normal" code is ok.

```
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    URL_API: process.env.URL_API || 'http://localhost:8000/',
  },
```

But I want use .env value like this in my nuxt.config.js

```
  auth: {
    strategies: {
      local: {
        token: {
          property: 'token',
          required: true,
          maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60
        },
        user: {
          property: 'user',
          autoFetch: false
        },
        clientID: true,
        endpoints: {
          login: { url: `${process.env.URL_API}/auth/login`, method: 'post' },
          logout: { url: `${process.env.URL_API}/auth/logout`, method: 'post' },
        },
        tokenType: ''
      }
    },
    redirect: {
      login: '/auth/login',
      logout: '/',
      callback: '/auth/login',
      home: '/'
    }
  },
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67705541/8816585

If you have some modules located in `nuxt.config.js`, you can only pass env variables through `process.env.MY_VARIABLE`.
It is working if you're linking to an external file tho.

Comment: What does "It is working if you're linking to an external file tho" mean exactly?

Comment: @kano external file as in a `plugin`, rather than directly into the `nuxt.config.js` file. This is quite an old answer tho.

Answer (score -2):

You can use [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) package to use variables from .env file in nuxt.config.js.

nuxt.config.js file should look like this:

```
// your imports here

require('dotenv').config()

// nuxt config here
```

Comment: In NuxtJS, there is runtime config, which allow us to not use dotenv.
I'm searching to use .env from with runtime config, not dotenv package

Comment: Please do not use `dotenv` since it's already baked in.