# configuring base url nuxt for digital ocean deployement

Tags: node.js, vue.js, deployment, nuxt.js, digital-ocean

i'm building ecommerce web app using nuxt and node.js/express. when i'm building locally i have no problem making axios api calls.  base url is configured as the following

```
const baseDomain = 'http://localhost:8080/';
```

then all i do is

```
async getProducts({ commit }, payload) {
        
        const reponse = await Repository.get(
            `${baseUrl}/products?${serializeQuery(payload)}`
        )
            .then(response => {
                commit('setProducts', response.data);
                return response.data;
            })
            .catch(error => ({ error: JSON.stringify(error) }));
        return reponse;
    },
```

now the problem is when i move my whole app to digital ocean, i tried the following changes

```
const baseDomain = 'https://0.0.0.0:8080/';
```

my nuxt.js config

```
export default {
    ssr: false,
    head: {
        titleTemplate: 'Lokazz',
        title: 'Lokazz',
        meta: [
            { charset: 'utf-8' },
            {
                name: 'viewport',
                content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1'
            },
            {
                hid: 'description',
                name: 'description',
                content:
                    'Lokazz'
            }
        ],
        link: [
            {
                rel: 'stylesheet',
                href:
                    'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:300,400,500,600,700&amp;amp;subset=latin-ext'
            }
        ]
    },

    css: [
        'swiper/dist/css/swiper.css',
        '~/static/fonts/Linearicons/Font/demo-files/demo.css',
        '~/static/fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css',
        '~/static/css/bootstrap.min.css',
        '~/assets/scss/style.scss'
    ],

    plugins: [
        { src: '~plugins/vueliate.js', ssr: false },
        { src: '~/plugins/swiper-plugin.js', ssr: false },
        { src: '~/plugins/vue-notification.js', ssr: false },
        { src: '~/plugins/axios.js'},
        { src: '~/plugins/lazyLoad.js', ssr: false },
        { src: '~/plugins/mask.js', ssr: false },
        { src: '~/plugins/toastr.js', ssr: false },
    ],


    buildModules: [
        '@nuxtjs/vuetify',
        '@nuxtjs/style-resources',
        'cookie-universal-nuxt'
    ],

    styleResources: {
        scss: './assets/scss/env.scss'
    },

    modules: ['@nuxtjs/axios', 'nuxt-i18n','vue-sweetalert2/nuxt', '@nuxtjs/auth-next', "bootstrap-vue/nuxt"],
    bootstrapVue: {
        bootstrapCSS: false, // here you can disable automatic bootstrapCSS in case you are loading it yourself using sass
        bootstrapVueCSS: false, // CSS that is specific to bootstrapVue components can also be disabled. That way you won't load css for modules that you don't use
       
    },

    i18n: {
        locales: [
            { code: 'en', file: 'en.json' },
        ],
        strategy: 'no_prefix',
        fallbackLocale: 'en',
        lazy: true,
        defaultLocale: 'en',
        langDir: 'lang/locales/'
    },

    router: {
        linkActiveClass: '',
        linkExactActiveClass: 'active',
    },
    server: {
        port: 8080, // default: 3000
        host: '0.0.0.0' // default: localhost 
        /// this one works fine , the digital ocean support team told me to do this.
    },
    auth: {
        strategies: {
          local: {
            token: {
              property: "token",
              global: true,
            },
            redirect: {
                "login": "/account/login",
                "logout": "/",
                "home": "/page/ajouter-produit",
                "callback": false
            },
            endpoints: {
              login: { url: "/login", method: "post" },
              logout: false, //  we don't have an endpoint for our logout in our API and we just remove the token from localstorage
              user:false
            }
          }
        }
      },
};
```

package.json file

```
{
    "name": "martfury_vue",
    "version": "1.3.0",
    "description": "Martfury - Multi-purpose Ecomerce template with vuejs",
    "author": "nouthemes",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "nuxt",
        "build": "nuxt build",
        "start": "nuxt start",
        "generate": "nuxt generate"
    },
    "config": {
        "nuxt": {
          "host": "0.0.0.0",
          "port": "8080"
        }
    },
}
```

server index.js config

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const cors = require('cors');
const url = 'mongodb+srv://****************************' // this works fine i manage to pull data from the cluster without a problem
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')


mongoose.connect(url, {useNewUrlParser:true}).then(()=>{
    const app = express();

    // middlleware
    app.use(express.json())
    app.use(cors());

    //products routes 
    const products = require('./product/product.router');
    app.use('/', products)
    //users routes
    const users = require('./user/user.router');
    app.use('/', users)
    const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

    app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`));
    }).catch(error => console.log(error.reason));
const con = mongoose.connection

con.on('open', () => {
    console.log('connected...')
})
```

here's my github repo and file structure. the server and api folder is lokazz_api.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your project runs fine with an `.env` file, it should work as good on production.

DO NOT commit `.env` but rather aim to your Digitalocean dashboard and look in the settings. You should see a place where you can input your pair and then proceed.

As shown here: https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/app-platform/how-to/use-environment-variables/#using-bindable-variables-within-environment-variables

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use Environment variables for this.

Install `dotenv` in your project and then configure it in your `nuxt.config.js` file.

Create a `.env` file in your root directory, and then set a key-value pair like this:

`VUE_APP_BASE_URL="<value>"`

Note you need to prefix your keys with `VUE_APP`.

Your `.env` should look like this:
`VUE_APP_BASE_URL="http://localhost:8080/"`

You can modify your variable to this: `const baseDomain = process.env.BASE_URL;`

Remember to add the `.env` file in the `.gitignore` file.

On your digital ocean terminal, you can create a `.env` file using the `touch .env` command, and then use Vim or Nano to modify the file.

Comment: Please do not use `dotenv` since it's already baked into Nuxt. Rather use publicRuntime as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67705541/8816585

Comment: @wisdom but the problem is it won't work when i deploy it on digital ocean. I need it to work there ....

Comment: @SbZakaria why? You can totally set env variables there too. I don't see the blocker here.

Comment: @kissu so what you are saying is that if i deploy it with with the VUE_APP_BASE_URL="localhost:8080"  everything will work fine??

Comment: Yes, this will work only if your local is using the same config.

Comment: @SbZakaria you probably need some different values on production but the idea is the same yeah. Usually you do have URL/crrdentials/alike for dev and other ones for production.