# How to access environment variable in imports in Nuxt.js

Tags: environment-variables, components, nuxt.js

I have a pretty standard component that imports and uses other components. I want to conditionally import one of its child components based on a value set in my .env file, but it doesn't seem like either `process.env` or `this` is accessible outside the `export default {}` script object.

So I'd like to find out how I can access values set in my .env file from here, if it's even possible?

Here's a recreation of what I'm trying to do:

`my-component.vue`

```html
<template>
  <!-- irrelevant markup -->
</template>

<script>
  import ChildComp from process.env.VAL === 'thing' ? '@/components/child1' : '@/components/child2';
  // or even ` ... from this.$config.VAL === ... `

  export default {
    components: { ChildComp },

    // more irrelevant code here...
  }
</script>
```

So that pretty much shows what I'm trying to do. I know that the nuxt way of doing env vals is by declaring them in the `publicRuntimeConfig` and `privateRuntimeConfig` objects in `nuxt.config.js`, so that's what I've done, and now my `.VAL` is accessible in my component through `this.$config.VAL` - just not outside `export default {}` -_-

Any thoughts or ideas will be appreciated. And let me know if you need more to go on.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use .env variables in Nuxt 2 or 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67703133/how-to-use-env-variables-in-nuxt-2-or-3)

Comment: Please give a read to this article too: https://nuxtjs.org/tutorials/moving-from-nuxtjs-dotenv-to-runtime-config

Answer (score -1):

In Nuxt you have no access to your `.env` vars by default as the Nuxt App can also be served without any server.

So you need to add your env-vars to the [nuxt config](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-env/) in order to access them.

```js
export default {
  env: {
    baseUrl: process.env.BASE_URL || 'http://localhost:3000'
  }
}
```

In the app, you can access them like

- `process.env.baseUrl`
- `context.env.baseUrl`

Comment: I'm not sure that this is the way to go looking at this page of the documentation: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-env#the-env-property