# NuxtJS privateRuntimeConfig

Tags: nuxt.js

When using a value coming from .env in `privateRuntimeConfig` it works correctly, however when changing `pages` it becomes `undefined`, does anyone know why this behavior?

Comment: Hi, please show use some code. Also, give a read to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67705541/8816585

Comment: As a reminder, `privateRuntimeConfig` is available on **server only** as stated here: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-runtime-config/#privateruntimeconfig

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.