# How to use PublicRuntimeConfig variables inside nuxt.config.js?

Tags: nuxt.js

In my nuxt.config.js file I create some variables which are needed in multiple parts of my application. My main objective is this:

In this example I use the about.vue page. The name and url of a link are defined in the nuxt.config file. An object is created that stores both `custom name` as `url` of `about`. I want to replace the standard URL of *homepage.com/about* to *homepage.com/custom-about*. I should get `custom-about` from the `$config.ABOUT.URL`. I tried both $config.ABOUT.URL as this.ABOUT.URL but both won't work. How can I pass the variable created in publicRuntimeConfig to router inside the same nuxt.config.js file?

`.env`

```sh
ABOUT_NAME='Custom about'
ABOUT_URL='custom-about'
```

`nuxt.config.js`

```js
publicRuntimeConfig: {
  PAGE_TITLE: process.env.PAGE_TITLE || "Company",

  ABOUT: {
    NAME: process.env.ABOUT_NAME || "About us",
    URL: process.env.ABOUT_URL || "/about"
  },
}
...
router: {
  extendRoutes: routesIn => {
    routesIn.forEach(r => {
      if (r.path.includes("/about")) {
      r.path = r.path.replace("/about","/" + this.ABOUT.URL);
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: Hi, does this one help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/67705541/8816585

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, this doesn't help. This explains how to use the variables in other documents/components. This works just fine. I need to pass the variables inside the nuxt.config file.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately not. But I found out that it is possible to write plain JS between the import and export section, so this allows me to create an object which I can use throughout the full document.

Answer (score 2):

In [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70007235/how-to-use-publicruntimeconfig-variables-inside-nuxt-config-js?noredirect=1#comment123757156_70007235), there is a part with `If you need this variable for a Nuxt module`, but yeah, I'll edit it to basically add `... or anything at all in your nuxt.config.js file` I guess.

Here, you should use this

```js
r.path = r.path.replace("/about", "/", process.env.ABOUT_URL)
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't need the value from process.env but from $config.

Comment: @JeffreyvanZwam You don't have access to `$config` in `nuxt.config.js`. As explained [here](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/concepts/context-helpers), `$config` is available in Nuxt's context aka in `asyncData`, `plugins` , `middleware`  and `nuxtServerInit`. Why couldn't you use `process.env` here?