# Where to deploy Strapi backend and use it with Nuxt frontend?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, nuxt.js, content-management-system, netlify, strapi

I have a Nuxt frontend deployed to Google App Engine.
Can I deploy Strapi to Netlify? Or is there a platform where I can deploy Strapi for free?
Also after deploying what is the exact setting which needs to be changed in Nuxt?

My settings with **apollo**.

```js
apollo: {
  clientConfigs: {
    default: {
      httpEndpoint: 'http://localhost:1337/graphql',
    },
  },
},
```

**@nuxtjs/strapi** Settings in [Documentation](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/content-api/integrations/nuxt-js.html#get-request-your-collection-type).

```js
modules: ['@nuxtjs/strapi'],
strapi: {
  entities: ['restaurants', 'categories'],
  url: 'http://localhost:1337'
},
```

I guess I have to place the Heroku URL in place of localhost:1337 if I use @nuxtjs/strapi which I am not using currently?
What if I want to use apollo? Where should I put the Heroku URL as it has httpEndpoint field for graphql URL?

Comment: Use `process.env.STRAPI_URL` in place of the hardcoded `http://localhost:1337/graphql`. Then, in local, you can put the local URL in your `.env` file and on Google App Engine, you'll be able to have the actual Heroku URL of your Strapi app. As explained in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67705541/8816585

Comment: The env is accessible when I console.log(process.env) in store index.js file. But it is empty object when console logged inside mounted(). Why?

Comment: You should not use `process.env` but rather `publicRuntimeConfig` here, as explained in [my answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70051914/where-to-deploy-strapi-backend-and-use-it-with-nuxt-frontend?noredirect=1#comment123837844_70051914). Also, `process.env` does not work but `process.env.myvariable` should because webpack is replacing the actual variable with a static value (your env value).

Comment: publicRuntimeConfig is working as it should. Also, can I do this in strapi options so that I can fetch data from localhost when in development and actual strapi url when deployed to app engine.  strapi: {
    url: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? process.env.STRAPI_URL : 'http://localhost:1337'
  }

Comment: This is not how env variables work. Locally, set `STRAPI_URL` in your `.env` file. And in production, set `STRAPI_URL` to the actual URL. That way, you have only one variable with the actual value coming from the env itself.

Comment: Yes, Thank You so much. It is working as expected. My Strapi backend is deployed to Heroku. And it was easy to integrate it with Nuxt using @nuxtjs/strapi module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strapi needs a Node.js server, so Heroku is a good idea. They do have a free tier dyno that takes some time to spin up but there is no issue since you will use it as a headless CMS.

Once deployed, you'll need to update the URL of Strapi in `nuxt.config.js`. And I guess that it's pretty much all.

You will have all of your info in their official docs: https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/deployment/hosting-guides/heroku.html

Comment: Thank You for answering. I have updated my question. Can you please solve my query at the last?