# Unexpected token while access an env variable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, environment-variables, nuxt.js

I'm trying to add environment variable inside `.env` file in my nuxt project.

My Nuxt.js version is `2.15.3`

Here is a snippet from my `nuxt.config.js`:

```js
export default {
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL
  },
  ssr: false,
  target: 'static',
}
```

Here is my `.env` file:

`BASE_URL=https://my-url.smth`

But when I run `npm run dev` then nuxt gives error:

`ERROR in ./.env 1:14 Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:14) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file.`

I was guided by this article https://nuxtjs.org/tutorials/moving-from-nuxtjs-dotenv-to-runtime-config/

Also it DOES NOT work with the old way through the `@nuxtjs/dotenv`.

Comment: Could you please show your entire `nuxt.config.js` where related to the env? also, are you using `nuxt-vite`?

Comment: Also, maybe try to write it as `BASE_URL="https://my-url.smth"` The issue here, being a "loader", it is probably not directly a matter of env variables but more of a structure one or the way that your project is setup. Do you have a `package.json` to share? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the variable in your `.env` file in **double quotes** (and not single quotes) like this `BASE_URL="https://my-url.smth"`.

---

I've written an [in-depth answer on using env files with nuxt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67705541/8816585) with more information on the subject.
As mentioned in it, please do not use the `@nuxtjs/dotenv` package.

If you still have an issue, we'll probably need more details or at least a [repro](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help you more efficiently.