# How to create a build for multiple environments in Nuxt?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, dotenv

I am building a Nuxt application where I will have two environments **staging and production**, the local should also be considered as staging, now I need to create some commands and generate builds for production and staging, which will be deployed on two separate servers.

I have two questions

1. The command

```
npm run generate
```

always generate a production build, I checked it using

```js
console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)
```

How can I generate a new build where the env should be something like staging?

2. I want to create some `.env` files for holding some env related variables, but I am confused about how can I create multiple env files for multiple envs (staging and production).

I understand my question is a bit of research orientation, I spent days researching on the internet, but either the blogs are unrelated or confusing. I never really got what I was looking for, can someone point me into the right direction?

Comment: `NODE_env` needs to be defined on the staging platform, same goes for the env files. Meaning that if you want some variable locally, set it in `.env`, if you want a specific variable for staging/production on Heroku, AWS or alike, set the env variable there (not in an `.env` but on some dashboard/settings tab).

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `generate` uses the default `production` if nothing is passed. If you give it a specific value, either in `.env` or by prefixing `npm run generate`, it should be good!

Comment: @kissu I generated a build by defining NODE_ENV=staging in .env nothing changed still shows production when i create a build

Comment: It's because the build will overwrite the env variable at build time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As told above, you can do
`NODE_ENV="staging" npm run generate`
while building the app, even tho this is [not recommended](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/6611#issuecomment-748618960) and you should probably just use another env variable like `ENV` and make conditionals based on this one for your app.

If you want more details on how to use env variables, you can look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67705541/8816585).

Then, the way env variables work still applies to what I said about AWS/Heroku etc...

Answer (score 0):

use `nuxt --dotenv` and pass the path to your env file like .env.production
Example package.json:

```
{
  "scripts":{
    "prod":"NODE_ENV=production && nuxt --dotenv .env.production"
  }
}
```