# Nuxt image keeps breaking on page change

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have image displayed on my Nuxt page but anytime I navigate away from it back the image breaks and I do not know why.

I have this in my code

```html
<img :src="baseUrl + 'storage/'+ front.featured_image" alt="post-title" />
```

and my script

```
data: () => ({
  frontpage: [],
    baseUrl: process.env.BASE_URL
}),
async asyncData({ $axios }) {
  const response = await $axios.get('/api/frontpage')
  return { frontpage: response.data.posts }
},
```

I have a `.env` file and I have the following inside it `BASE_URL=http://localhost/` and I also have the following inside `nuxt.config.js`

```js
env:{
  baseUrl: process.env.BASE_URL || 'http://localhost/'
}
```

My API is built using laravel and it is loading from `http://localhost/` but Nuxt keeps going back to `localhost:3000` on page change.

Comment: `process.env.BASE_URL` is the base URL of your nuxt app which is `http://localhost:3000`

Comment: You can start by [reading this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67705541/8816585). Where is your `featured_image` state defined. How is it broken (what do you see in the Vue devtools)? Do you use SSG or SSR? As suggested above, maybe try to rename the variable. Maybe try with a `fetch()` hook. You're not using `a` tags to move I hope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check my previous answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67705541/8816585

This may help

```js
export default {
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    baseUrl: process.env.BASE_URL,
  },
}
```

Otherwise, this [configuration of Axios](https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options#runtime-config) may also help!