# Environment variable with netlify.toml file

Tags: git, vue.js, nuxt.js, netlify, toml

I'm trying to set a environment variable when I push on a certain branch on my repo (the 'next' branch), the goal is that I want this variable to be defined only in this branch.

I've read the netlify documentation and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong:

https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/file-based-configuration/

So I've used the following code in my netlify.toml file:

```yaml
[context.next.environment]
  SITE_BRANCH = "next"
```

I also tried `[context.next]`

My variable never appears in process.env

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong ? Thanks

EDIT

This is my `nuxt.config.js` file:

```js
export default {
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    SITE_BRANCH: 'process.env.SITE_BRANCH'
  }
}
```

This is my `.env` file:

```
SITE_BRANCH=next
```

Comment: Not sure myself about the thing here. Your env variable is named `SITE_BRANCH`? Then, it should be in `process.env.SITE_BRANCH` right? Be careful because `console.log`'ing just `process.env` will give you an empty object normally. On top of that, [this is how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67705541/8816585) you usually use env variables in Nuxt.

Comment: I tried `console.log`ing `process.env.SITE_BRANCH` and it returned undefined.

Comment: Where? Could you please edit your question with some code? Also, is `SITE_BRANCH` the name of your env variable here?

Comment: Could you be sure that you can achieve a proper working flow with a simple static `.env` file at first? Before going into the dynamic netlify one.

Comment: I also use `publicRuntimeConfig` and `privateRuntimeConfig` in my nuxt.config for other variables. But I didn't try it for this one since it was depending on the branch name, I thought it was netlify that had the information. Not sure if what I'm saying is clear.

Comment: At the end, it will still be the same: passing down the variable to your app so you can expect it to work in the same way (if it's coming from a file or from Netlify, it should still be similar). I still do recommend trying with a static `.env` file to be sure that this is working.

Comment: Okay, so I've tried with a `.env` file and it's working, I get the variable by using `this.$config.SITE_BRANCH`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the syntax is more like this (indentation is important)

```yaml
[context."feat/my-cool-branch"]
  SITE_BRANCH = "next"
```

[This part](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/file-based-configuration/#deploy-contexts) of the documentation goes more into details.

Comment: It seems to be working with this code: `[context."next".environment]
  SITE_BRANCH = "next"` and of course the publicRuntimeConfig