# How to create Nuxt route full path in the data object?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to integrate [social share](https://github.com/nicolasbeauvais/vue-social-sharing#readme) in my nuxt application, I am trying to set my page URL in the data object. Following is my code please guide me on how I can set `sharing.url` like we do with `NuxtLink`?

```html
<NuxtLink :to="{ name: 'posts-slug', params: { slug: post.slug } }">
  some title
</NuxtLink>
```

`social share component`

```html
<template>
  <ShareNetwork
    v-for="network in networks"
    :url="sharing.url"
    :title="sharing.title"
    :description="sharing.description"
  >
  </ShareNetwork>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      sharing: {
        // how can I set following url with the post prop, like I did with Nuxt link which creates href
        url: 'https://mywebsite.com/posts/wide-angle-mountain-view',
        title: 'Say hi to Vite!',
        description: 'This week',
      },
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Wasn't clear that you wanted to use a specific `social share` npm package at first. So, what do you want exactly? Something like `this.$route.fullPath`?

Comment: I want to create a link in sharing data object, for the time being I did something like this ```url:process.env.NUXT_SERVER_BASE_URL + '/posts/' + this.post.slug'``` is there any better way than this

Comment: You can properly use the env variables yeah: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67705541/8816585

Comment: Thanks,it looks like what I did is also fine. I'll try and update my code in the morning, I'm not on the system right now. You can post it in the answer I'll accept it

Comment: Can I dm you this weekend just for a suggestion overview. I'm working on side project I was thinking from 2 years. Finally started it last month and should get finished this weekend. Before sending it to Google for crawling, getting advice from you would be really great

Comment: Alright, reach out to me on Discord (or other links available on my profile).

Comment: Sure thanks, I'll message you on Twitter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have something like this

```js
:url="`${nuxtServerBaseUrl}/posts/${post.slug}`"
```

with `nuxtServerBaseUrl` being your `publicRuntimeConfig` env variable.

As of regarding the configuration [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67705541/8816585).