# How to access environment variables in a composable in Nuxt3?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

In my nuxt 3 App, for data fetching I wanna set a baseURL for all my API calls. As I get this baseURL from enviroment variable. How to set the the baseURL?

I warp the `useFetch` with composables, but then I can't get the baseURL as `useRuntimeConfig()` is not accessable there.

```js
// My composables function
const baseURL = "how to get baseURL from process.env";

export const myFetch = async (url: string) => {
  const options = {
    baseURL: baseURL,
  };

  return await useFetch(url, options);
}
```

Comment: Here is a comment that may be relevant in your case: https://github.com/nuxt/framework/discussions/3215#discussioncomment-3088206 Otherwise, the rest of the discussion is also interesting.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It working. I just have to declear  the `useRuntimeConfig()` inside my composable function

Comment: Posted an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the runtime config by doing so

```js
export default () => {
  const config = useRuntimeConfig()

  console.log(config)
}
```

As shown here: https://github.com/nuxt/framework/discussions/3215#discussioncomment-3088206

Comment: anyone know how to do this in Nuxt 2?

Comment: @v3nt if I'm not mistaken, there are no composable in Nuxt2.

Comment: there are is you use composition api 

Comment: Yeah I would also be interested in how I can use this with nuxt 2.17, nuxt-bridge and the composition-api

Comment: @Merc https://stackoverflow.com/a/67705541/8816585

Comment: Thanks for the link. It does not really cover how I can use useRuntimeConfig in my vuex store though. I tried but I get errors all the time...

Comment: @Merc you should rather be using Pinia anyway. Feel free to post a brand new question.

Comment: I am moving away from vuex anyway. Instead of Pinia I use composables now to manage (shared) states. I have an older project where we still work with vuex but I needed to overhaul the project and update and now my nuxt.config includes `runtimeConfig` AND `env`. The latter to still have access to my env variables in a vuex store module. I wanted to get rid of that. Maybe someday I will remove the vuex store completely.