# How can I access environment variables (process.env) in composable when using @nuxtjs/composition-api

Tags: environment-variables, nuxt.js, vue-composition-api, dotenv

I want to access env variables in a composable written in nuxt2 (not 3!) together with the composition-api plugin.

How can I do that?
This approach to use `useRuntimeConfig` probably only works with nuxt 3: [How to access environment variables in a composable in Nuxt3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73206341/how-to-access-environment-variables-in-a-composable-in-nuxt3)

I tried to use `useContext` and in there I see that the returned object by doing

```
import {useContext} from '@nuxtjs/composition-api'
...
const context = useContext()
```

includes a key `env`. But this `env` key only contains the env variables defined in the nuxt config.

```
  env: {
    BACKEND_URL: process.env.BACKEND_URL,
  }
```

So I could access it by `context.env.BACKEND_URL`...

Is this right approach? How could I get just all the content of my .env file, which I can do in the options API by using `process.env`?