# Nuxt, doesnt load NUXT_ENV var

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Hello I have an env var like the following in the nuxt.config.js

```
env: {
   BAR: process.env.BAR
}
```

The problem is that I need to load from os env var instead of `.env` file so I tried to use NUXT_ENV_ like this:

I load the env var with

```
export NUXT_ENV_BAR='value'
```

1 Try

```
env: {
   BAR: process.env.NUXT_ENV_BAR
}
....
console.log(process.env.BAR)
....
```

2 Try

```
....
env: {
   NUXT_ENVBAR: process.env.NUXT_ENV_BAR
}
console.log(process.env.NUXT_ENVBAR)
....
```

I tried the same with `publicRuntimeConfig` instead of `env`, but didn't work too.

How can I set os env var inside nuxt.js app?

Thanks

Comment: Tried that? https://stackoverflow.com/a/67705541/8816585

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set an object in JSON the format is `key` : `value`. You can not use `=`.

So your code should be:

```js
env: {
   BAR: process.env.BAR
}
```

To manage your custom Nuxt env you can use https://github.com/nuxt-community/dotenv-module `dotenv` module or `publicRuntimeConfig` as you said.

If you want to use the 'publicRuntimeConfig' attribute in your `nuxt.config.js` file just implement this code:

```js
 publicRuntimeConfig: {
   BAR: 'yourValue',
 }
```

Then you can access this config data with `$config` as `$config.BAR`. (To test your config in your browser just write `__NUXT__.config` in the console tab)

Comment: The questios is that In `your value` I need to read NUXT_ENV var, because I cannot read from a .env file i need read from os env var, and that is not working, so how can I do to work with that?

Comment: Have you read the dotenv module doc you have in the link? It allows you to set .env files and read them into your nuxt config. Then map your variables as you want like my example.

Comment: Finnaly was docker error.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a file e.g. `serverVariables.js` with the server variables that you want to define at the location of your choice in your project.

```
export default {
  BAR: process.env.BAR || '<your default value>',
};
```

Next, inside your `nuxt.config.js`, you could import those variables at the very top like;

```
import serverVariables from '~/serverVariables';
```

Next you could map those variables to your `publicRuntimeConfig` like;

```
publicRuntimeConfig: {
    BAR: serverVariables.BAR,
}
```

You could then access it anywhere in your components like;

```
$config.BAR
```