# How add server control panel codesandbox to my vue project?

Tags: vuejs2, codesandbox

I have vue project in codesandbox, but I would like add secret keys into my project (like token) for correct start project. How I can do it?
Or may be you can advice method for hiding token in my vue project on codesandbox?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Now that you did added your key, you can follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67705541/8816585 You of course don't need the `.env` part anymore because this is probably what the `Secret keys` section is doing here.

Comment: @kissu I didn't add key to project. I don't know how to add this button with server control panel in my vue project

Comment: what button?  what server control panel?  you haven't explained what those mean and what exactly you want

Comment: @yoduh I want add token to my vue project in codesandbox, but I don't know how to do it private. I want share with project for asking questions, but token must be hidden.

Comment: At the end, it you need a repro or alike you don't really need to bother with that. Just mock enough data or do that somewhere else (more work).

Comment: Or try to see if you can somehow provide a limited token (rate, expiration etc...).