# How to read environment variables

Tags: vue.js, nuxtjs3

env file is in root directory. I run my server with `npm run dev`

.env

```
STRIPE_KEY=1234
```

When trying to use it in a js file
`const API_KEY = process.env.STRIPE_KEY`

Im getting following error:

`Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'STRIPE_KEY')`

Comment: Hi, did you tried that one? https://stackoverflow.com/a/67705541/8816585

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use .env variables in Nuxt 2 or 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67703133/how-to-use-env-variables-in-nuxt-2-or-3)

Comment: @some-user pretty much what I posted above yeah.