# Specify config file in nuxt 3

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I have a Nuxt 3 application (3.0.0-rc.13) generating a static website, and have to deploy to two locations:

1. Firebase hosting
2. Amazon S3 bucket

Hosting on Firebase needs a baseUrl of `/`, and Amazon needs a different baseUrl (`/2223/`). This can be configured in nuxt config, however I cannot find an cli option to specify which config file to use.

I have tried these, but they just pick the default `nuxt.config.ts`.

```bash
nuxt generate -c nuxt.config.amazon.ts
nuxt generate --config-file nuxt.config.amazon.ts
```

I found [this issue](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/391) that added support to it for Nuxt 2, but I cannot find anything about it for Nuxt 3. Am I missing something or is it just not supported at all?

Comment: You could use environment variables with an `.env` file, still the best way to handle such use-case.

Comment: Here is an exhaustive answer on how to work with those: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67705541/8816585

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the solution @kissu
If anyone faces the same problem, here is how I implemented it:

**package.json scripts:**

```json
"generate": "cross-env DEPLOY_TARGET=default nuxt generate",
"generate:amazon": "cross-env DEPLOY_TARGET=amazon nuxt generate",
```

**nuxt.config.ts**

```js
const getBaseUrl = () => {
  const environment = process.env.DEPLOY_TARGET;

  switch (environment) {
    case "amazon":
      return "/2223/";
    default:
      return "/";
  }
};

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  app: {
    baseURL: getBaseUrl(),
  },
});
```

Comment: I recommend doing that the other way around actually (no need for conditions). But you are to decide at the end.