# Deploying Nuxt on Netlify

Tags: environment-variables, nuxt.js, netlify

I am trying to deploy my nuxt site on Netlify, it is deployed But I am facing some issues with environment variables. When I try to log in to the site, it's working correctly & moves to the index page. But when I am trying to search for something on the nuxt app the API fails due to an `undefined environment variable` even if I am using the same environment variable for the login API call. I am adding the environment variable here.

[image]

It's the `successful API call with environment variables`,

[image]

It's the `unsuccessful API call with the same environment variables`. Its also embedded in the other domain at the start of the API call.
[image]

Comment: Does it work locally? Which version of Nuxt are you using? Do you have a nuxt config to share? Do you use an `.env` file? Why are your variables named `VUE_APP`? Did you checked that one? https://stackoverflow.com/a/67705541/8816585

Comment: @kissu Yes, it works locally fine even on another server. I am using this `nuxt@2.15.8` version. Yes, I am also using the `.env` file. I don't understand that why login API works & others APIs don't work even with the same environment variables on `Netlify`. By the way, I am not accessing the environment variables in `nuxt.config.js`.

Comment: What do you mean? How are you accessing it? You can also try on Vercel for testing purposes. Why are your variables named `VUE_APP`?