# Nuxt 3 environment variables for static site

Tags: environment-variables, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I am trying to access environment variables from the client side on my Nuxt project.
I have a simple `.env` file which contains:

```
NUXT_GITHUB_TOKEN=mytoken
```

And from a `SimpleComponent.vue` I am trying to access it like so:

```js
created() {
  const runtimeConfig = useRuntimeConfig();
  console.log(runtimeConfig.NUXT_GITHUB_TOKEN);
}
```

That `console.log` there will print undefined. Since I am trying to save a github token I **can't** set the variable inside the `nuxt.config.js` file.

How can I get this done in Nuxt3?

Comment: Hi, did you give a try to that one? https://stackoverflow.com/a/67705541/8816585

Comment: @kissu Thanks to point me to that one. It did the trick. Go ahead and mark this question as a duplicate.