# Nuxt 3 expose .env file to all

Tags: environment-variables, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, .env

I'm building a Nuxt 3 app, but I have a problema with .env file. 
In production if I navigate **[www.mydomain.com/.env](http://www.mydomain.com/.env)** i can see al sensible data like API key.

I'trying to use runtimeConfig with apiSecret like this

```
runtimeConfig: {


// Keys within public, will be also exposed to the client-side
apiSecret: {
    //stripe_pk: process.env.STRIPE_PK,
    //client_id: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
 api_key: example

},
```

but I encountered the same problem. Where is the mistake?

Comment: Gave a try to [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67705541/8816585)? It also depends on where you're calling it, more details are overall welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is problem of your production server. In server config u should disble access to .env file.

Example for nginx:

```
server {
    ...
    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }
    ...
}
```