# How to use .env file in Nuxt 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, infinity

Am using Nuxt-3 as my framework for the project and am very new to the framework too and when I was integrating api for my project and I was getting the response later when I tried to use api as global variable from the .env file in the root; but am unable to get the response as am getting error on the console hence forth kindly guide me on the right path in a simple way of explanation so I can sort the issue as well learn new concepts.
I installed the dependencies with:
npm install --save-dev @nuxtjs/dotenv

The code I tried was:

```
<template>

</template>
<script setup>
import axios from 'axios'

axios.defaults.baseURL = process.env.API_URL
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = process.env.API_KEY

const response = await this.$axios.get('/pgs').then(response => response.data)
console.log(response)
</script>
```

Comment: Which error? The question lacks clear problem statement. If you don't have a value from env then the request stuff is redundant. env is not currently in use. See https://nuxtjs.org/tutorials/moving-from-nuxtjs-dotenv-to-runtime-config/

Comment: Does that one answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/67705541/8816585

Answer (score 5):

You don't need any dependency when you use .env file for your project. In all my projects, this is process I do when I store important data.

1. Create a .env file
2. Add data e.g `EMAIL=test@gmail.com`
3. In your `nuxt.config.ts` file, add this `runtimeConfig: { EMAIL: process.env.EMAIL, },`
4. To access it in the backend, your need to use the `useRuntimeConfig` composables See more details https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-runtime-config#useruntimeconfig.

See example on stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-g534de?file=nuxt.config.ts

Answer (score 3):

Runtime config values can be automatically replaced by matching environment variables at runtime. By naming your `.env` variables starting with `NUXT_`  which uses `_` to separate keys and case changes. No need to pass any `proceess.env` in this scenario. This example taken from the docs.

```
// .env file
NUXT_API_SECRET=####
NUXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE=###
```

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  runtimeConfig: {
    apiSecret: '', // can be overridden by NUXT_API_SECRET environment variable
    public: {
      apiBase: '', // can be overridden by NUXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE environment variable
    }
  },
})
```

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
  const config = useRuntimeConfig()

  console.log('Runtime config:', config.public.apiBase) 
  if (process.server) {
    console.log('API secret:', config.apiSecret)
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Indeed, good video for the reference: https://youtu.be/_FYV5WfiWvs I'll update my answer somewhere else too!

Answer (score 1):

You can create `.env` files in your root directory by using following naming convention:

1. for dev environment, you can name it as `.env.dev`,
2. for prod environment, you can name it as `.env.prod`

Next step is to add `publicRuntimeConfig` in your nuxt config:

```
publicRuntimeConfig:{
  API_KEY: process.env.NODE_ENV == 'prod' ? 'AAA' : 'BBB'
}
```

Now you can use `API_KEY` in your components as:

```
this.$config.API_KEY
```

Comment: Don't use files like `dev` and `prod`, set those per environment rather.

Comment: Yeah correct, that is only for reference

Comment: Can confuse people tho, making them think that this is how you manage variables per environment. It's like when everybody makes a `v-for` loop with the `index` as a `key`, yeah it's for quick and dirty examples but it's just plain wrong tbh. Giving a proper answer with a disclaimer or just not talking about the [bad approach](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#should-i-have-multiple-env-files) is probably better.

Comment: @kissu in the above answer, how can we indicate that NODE_ENV is prod or dev?  I mean when we need to build for prod then how we can get `prod` value from `process.env.NODE_ENV` ?