Use enviroment variables in NUXT3 on production
Im using a nuxt3 app as frontend of a web app, and i need to be able to set the endpoint of the httpRequest once the proyect has been built and is working on my IIS. I thought that with enviroment variables i could be able to do so, but i dont really know how to use them in nuxt3.
My nuxt.config file is:
import type { NuxtConfig } from "@nuxt/types";
require('dotenv').config()

const config: NuxtConfig = {
  runtimeConfig: {
    public: {
      apiBase: process.env.NUXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE ?? '/error',
    }
  },
  
  ... 
};

export default config;

And my HttpService class uses something like:
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'){
      url.value = new URL(useRuntimeConfig().public.apiBase + 'Api/');
    }
    else{
      url.value = new URL('https://localhost:xxxx/Api/');
    }

When i use the app in develpment mode is working fie, using the ip i have in my .env file:
NUXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE=http://xxxxxxxx:xxxxxx/
But when i do : 'nuxt generate' to build the project, the value of the variable apiBase is always the value i had on my local enviroment variable at the time a i built it. I create an enviroment variable at the server but gets ignored, what can i do? I did somehting wrong or this is how its supposed to work and i have to find another way of achiving my goal of being able to change the ip at runtime?

Give a try to that one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67703133/how-to-use-env-variables-in-nuxt-2-or-3/67705541#67705541 And use environment variables rather.

Did you add .env to .gitignore? Items in .env will cover environment variables.

@ZihanHu yes, i have .env in my gitignore
